# Appending trailing zeros to a oracle number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to format the `NUMBER` data type in Oracle as follows:

**Problem Statement:**

```
  -> Append trailing zeros to the ATM_CARD-NUMBER whose length is 14
```

**My Attempt:**

```
SELECT to_char(atm_card_nbr,'9999999999999900')as new_atm_nbr,atm_card_key from atm_card_dm where LENGTH(TRANSLATE(TO_CHAR(atm_card_nbr),'1234567890.-','1234567890'))=14;
```

**Result:**

[image]

I've gone through several Oracle related online sites but could not find the correct result. So, how can get the correct result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, I need to append trailing zeros i.e. if 46547575076852 then it should be 4654757507685200 @techdo

Comment: What should be the output of `45712728123560`?

Comment: It should be 4571272812356000 @techdo

Comment: Does `rpad` suffice your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT rpad(to_char(atm_card_nbr),16,'0') as new_atm_nbr,
       atm_card_key 
from atm_card_dm 
  where LENGTH(TRANSLATE(TO_CHAR(atm_card_nbr),'1234567890.-','1234567890'))=14;
```